# Is it possible to create a chart in Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, charts, uiimageview, xcode6, apple-watch

I am developing an application for Apple Watch, and I created charts to show the data in other iOS devices such as iPhone or iPad but I want to know can I create the charts to display data in Apple Watch too?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by drawing your charts in your extension to image and sending this to your WatchKit app and showing that image in an image view or group.

Drawing to image example:

```
var groupBackgroundImage: UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(groupBackgroundImageSize, false, 2.0)

    drawCompleteItemsCountInCurrentContext()

    let frame = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return frame
}
```

This example is from [Lister](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html), sample code from Apple to show best practices in app development, including Watch apps. You can take a look how they implement a circular count indicator in WatchKit Extension, but the exact code example is from file `GlanceBadge.swift`